# Jquery: почему не работает indexOf в массиве?

Tags: javascript, jquery, массивы, indexof

Есть массив, заполненный ячейками таблицы. Хочу, чтобы при клике на ту или иную ячейку мне возвращался её индекс в массиве. Но почему-то всегда возвращается -1. В чём здесь загвоздка?

```js
var arr = [];

$('td').each(function(){
   arr.push($(this));
});

$('td').click(function(){
   console.log(arr.indexOf($(this)));
});
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

table td {
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td></td><td></td><td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td><td></td><td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td><td></td><td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.0.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В вашем случае this - это элемент **td**. Замените **$(this)** на **this**

```js
var arr = [];

$('td').each(function(){
   arr.push(this);
});

$('td').click(function(){
   console.log(arr.indexOf(this));
});
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

table td {
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td></td><td></td><td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td><td></td><td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td><td></td><td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.0.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Проблема в выборе библиотеки.

```js
var arr = [...document.getElementsByTagName('td')];

$('td').click(e => {
   console.log(arr.indexOf(e.target));
});
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

table td {
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td></td><td></td><td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td><td></td><td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td><td></td><td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.0.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: А поясните, пожалуйста, свой ответ.

Comment: @humster_spb Проблема в том, что jQuery работает не с DOM элементами, а перерабатывает их в какие-то свои сущности. В чем конкретно проблема -  мне лень разбиратся. Вероятно $(this)  из одного и того же DOM элемента в двух разных местах дает два разных объекта..